# Selenium/webdriver network monitoring

Tags: networking, webdriver, http-request

I am looking for a way to monitor and record all requests that a browser makes while being used by selenium/webdriver to test a page. Something like the network pane in chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BrowserMob Proxy](http://proxy.browsermob.com/), while still young, looks like a promising solution for this. You'll find an example of how to use it with Selenium in its [README](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#readme). [Ruby bindings](https://github.com/jarib/browsermob-proxy-rb) were recently released.

Comment: Thanks. After some research came to the same conclusion.